# TypeError: mytitle is null

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to fill some contents in my form,but when i use a variable to get the object,there post a error `"TypeError: mytitle is null"`

Here is my code:

```
var num=0;
  function add(){
   var tr1=document.getElementById('itable').insertRow(1);
   var c0=tr1.insertCell(0);
   var c1=tr1.insertCell(1);
   var c2=tr1.insertCell(2);
   var c3=tr1.insertCell(3);
   var c4=tr1.insertCell(4);
   c0.innerHTML="<input type='checkbox' name='ck'/>";
   c1.innerHTML="<input type='text' style='width:150px;'id='news_title"+ num + "' name='news_title"+num+ "' value="+ document.getElementById('news_title').value+"></input>";
   c1.className="titlelimit";
   $(".titlelimit").wordLimit(10);
   c2.innerHTML="<input type='text' style='width:200px;' id='news_content"+num+"' name='news_content"+num+"' value="+ document.getElementById('news_content').value+"></input>";
   c2.className="detailindex";
   $(".detailindex").wordLimit(50);
   c3.innerHTML="<input type='text' readonly='readonly 'maxlength='4' style='width:70px;' id='news_type"+num+"' name='news_type"+num+"' value="+ document.getElementById('news_type').value+"></input>";
   c4.innerHTML="<input type='button' value='删除' onclick='del(this)' />";  
   num=num+1;
   $("#news_title").attr("value","");
   $("#news_content").attr("value","");
   $("#news_type").attr("value","");
  }

  window.onload = loadtable; 
  function loadtable() {
    var newstitle =  myform.mynewstitle.value
    alert(newstitle) 
    var titlearray = newstitle.split(",");
    for(i = 0;i<titlearray.length;i++){
        alert(titlearray[i]);
        add();
        var mytitle = document.getElementById('news_title'+num);
        mytitle.value = titlearray[i];
        num = num +1;   

   }
  }
```

Comment: remove num=num+1; from your add() function

Comment: You use an awful lot of raw javascript for someone that has jQuery on their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

num has a global scope, so at the end of add() its value it's 1

when you are in the for cycle, you are using incorrectly num to create your id name.

You have to use i.

```
var mytitle = document.getElementById('news_title'+i);
```

and this instruction it's usless, remove it last one of cicle for:

```
num = num +1;
```

so:

```
function loadtable() {
    var newstitle =  myform.mynewstitle.value
    alert(newstitle) 
    var titlearray = newstitle.split(",");
    for(i = 0;i<titlearray.length;i++){
        alert(titlearray[i]);
        add();
        var mytitle = document.getElementById('news_title'+i);
        mytitle.value = titlearray[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an element with `num` - `'news_title"+ num`

You then increment that with `num=num+1;`

You then try and find an element with `'news_title'+num`

If you created an element `'news_title0'`, by the time your look for it you're looking for an element with id `'news_title1'`

Remove the `num=num+1;` from your `add` function, since it already correctly exists in the loop in the `loadtable` function.

Comment: yes, you are right, i ignore the problem,thak you very much

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the following line,

```
var mytitle = document.getElementById('news_title'+num);
```

`mytitle` is not finding any element, you might want to check what `'news_title'+num` returns.